# smtp (set up using hmailserver) localhost to gmail message sending not working n python on Windows10

Tags: python, smtplib, hmail-server

I am trying to write a python code which will send error message to my email account. I  sending message using smtplib from localhost to my gmail account. I am trying following in jupyter notebook:

```
import smtplib

SERVER = "localhost"
LOGIN = "sourabh@localhost.com"
PASSWORD = "sourabh"

FROM = "sourabh@localhost.com"
TO = ["sourabhjbp@gmail.com"] # must be a list
SUBJECT = "Hello!"

TEXT = "This message was sent with Python's smtplib."

# Prepare actual message
message = """\
From: %s
To: %s
Subject: %s

%s
""" % (FROM, ", ".join(TO), SUBJECT, TEXT)

server = smtplib.SMTP(SERVER,port=25)
server.set_debuglevel(1)
server.login(LOGIN, PASSWORD)
server.sendmail(FROM, TO, message)
server.quit()
```

It quits with message "(221, 'goodbye')". Following is full debug log,

```
send: 'ehlo [192.168.56.1]\r\n'
reply: '250-localhost\r\n'
reply: '250-SIZE 20480000\r\n'
reply: '250-AUTH LOGIN PLAIN\r\n'
reply: '250 HELP\r\n'
reply: retcode (250); Msg: localhost
SIZE 20480000
AUTH LOGIN PLAIN
HELP
send: 'AUTH PLAIN AHNvdXJhYmhAbG9jYWxob3N0LmNvbQBzb3VyYWJo\r\n'
reply: '235 authenticated.\r\n'
reply: retcode (235); Msg: authenticated.
send: 'mail FROM:<sourabh@localhost.com> size=115\r\n'
reply: '250 OK\r\n'
reply: retcode (250); Msg: OK
send: 'rcpt TO:<sourabhjbp@gmail.com>\r\n'
reply: '250 OK\r\n'
reply: retcode (250); Msg: OK
send: 'data\r\n'
reply: '354 OK, send.\r\n'
reply: retcode (354); Msg: OK, send.
data: (354, 'OK, send.')
send: "From: sourabh@localhost.com\r\nTo: sourabhjbp@gmail.com\r\nSubject: Hello!\r\n\r\nThis message was sent with Python's smtplib.\r\n.\r\n"
reply: '250 Queued (0.032 seconds)\r\n'
reply: retcode (250); Msg: Queued (0.032 seconds)
data: (250, 'Queued (0.032 seconds)')
send: 'quit\r\n'
reply: '221 goodbye\r\n'
reply: retcode (221); Msg: goodbye
```

Answer (score 0):

The line 
reply: retcode (250); Msg: Queued (0.032 seconds)
data: (250, 'Queued (0.032 seconds)')

Says hMailServer has successfully accepted your Mail:

You should now see a new *.eml file in the Root of your hMailServer DATA folder
(a file with a name like {3f20b09b-2a35-4a16-a7e9-a510ea0f5eae.eml}
which contains your Message you sent via Python. It will automatically deleted
if your Email has reached the recipient.

For more Information, run hMailAdmin, go to settings and enable all Logging check boxes
and restart your hMailServer Windows Service / Deamon (or run from a Elevated Windows Command prompt net hmailserver stop & net hmailserver start.

PS: After Service restart, hMailAdmin (or any other COM-Client) needs to be closed
and restarted as well (just exit hMailAdmin and rerun it).